# Find if item in list a in range of items in sublist of list b

Tags: python, list, range

Let's say I have two lists.

```
x = [2,12,33,40,500]
y = ['1_4','9_11','38_50','300_400']
```

I would like to iterate through x and find determine if it is in the range of the other items in y (after splitting on '_'). If that is the case, it will break out of the loop since it does not need to check the others. I'm not trying to see how many ranges it falls into, only that it occurs once.

I think this code might work, but would like to double check.

```
x = [2,12,33,40,500]
y = ['1_4','9_11','38_50','300_400']

dict = {}

for i in x:
    for j in y:
        j_1 = int(j.split('_')[0])
        j_2 = int(j.split('_')[1])
        if i in range(j_1,j_2):
            dict[i] = 'yes'
            break
        else:
            dict[i] = 'no'
            #the else statement is what's tricking me
```

The solution should yield the following in this example:

```
dictt = {2:'yes',12:'no',33:'no',40:'yes',500:'no'}
```

Comment: I'm going to assume those `_` in `y` is a typo and should be `,`? Maybe update the post to reflect that.

Comment: You'll have to change the elements in `y` to be strings, as in the first example.

Comment: Just changed them to strings.

Comment: Sorry what about this isn't working? It gives the expected result...

Comment: I was making sure the else statement was correct, or if I needed an elif.

Comment: The `else` is in the wrong place.  You only want to assign `no` to the dict if _every_ element in y fails to match, but you're assigning 'no' if the _current_ element doesn't match.

Comment: I want to assign a no if no element in x falls within a range from an element of y.

Comment: ^ idd. I think the point John tries to make, is the fact that you may assign no to the range multiple times, before assigning a yes. Just a comment on the range, you can define it as tuples instead of strings, to remove the "split" each time.

Comment: The code works as long as both lists are sorted, despite of the redundant operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about checking if the number is in between any of the range of numbers in the `y` list.

```
>> x = [2,12,33,40,500]
>> y = ['1_4','9_11','38_50','300_400']
>> y_new = map(lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split('_'))), y)
# y_new = [(1, 4), (9, 11), (38, 50), (300, 400)]
>> def check_in_range(number):
        found = 'no'
        for each_range in y_new:
             if each_range[0] <= number <= each_range[1]:
                 found = 'yes'
        return found
>> dict(zip(x, map(check_in_range, x)))
>> {2: 'yes', 12: 'no', 33: 'no', 40: 'yes', 500: 'no'}
```

Note:
Otherwise, if you are using Python 2, always use `xrange` and not `range`.
xrange will not keep all the numbers in the memory which range does. This will be an issue when the range is bigger. Python3 will default to xrange.

Comment: This worked on python2 and not python3. Do you know why?

Comment: No errors, but the wrong output. When I used python3 I had to write y_new = list(map(lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split('_'))), y)). and then it worked.

Comment: Oh, you are trying to check the `y_new` data. In Python3, it will return a map object. It releases items on demand like a generator. But your result should be generated normally.

Comment: I updated the question. Could you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57877954/if-element-in-list-is-in-in-range-of-another-element-from-another-list

Answer (score 2):

Since you are testing a case versus any of the combinations within the list `y`, why not use `any`?

```
x = [2,12,33,40,500]
y = ['1_4','9_11','38_50','300_400']

y_new = [(int(a),int(b)) for i in y for a,b in zip(i.split("_"),i.split("_")[1:])]

l = {item:"Yes" if any(a<item<b for a,b in y_new) else "No" for item in x}

print (l)

#{2: 'Yes', 12: 'No', 33: 'No', 40: 'Yes', 500: 'No'}
```

Comment: Will this work with large lists? For instance, list x is going to be around 3 million numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It does work.  As you wrote it.

```
x = [2,12,33,40,500]
y = ['1_4','9_11','38_50','300_400']
dict = {}

for i in x:
    for j in y:
        j_1 = int(j.split('_')[0])
        j_2 = int(j.split('_')[1])
        if i in range(j_1,j_2):
            dict[i] = 'yes'
            break
        else:
            dict[i] = 'no'
```

Returns output:

```
{2: 'yes', 12: 'no', 33: 'no', 40: 'yes', 500: 'no'}
```