# If element in list is in in range of another element from another list

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested-loops

Below is a question that is an extension of a question I asked a month ago.

[Find if item in list a in range of items in sublist of list b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487466/find-if-item-in-list-a-in-range-of-items-in-sublist-of-list-b)

Let's suppose I have two lists:

```
x = ['2_12_20','2_40_60','4_45_70']
y = ['2_16','2_18','4_60','3_400']
```

In a biological context, these numbers refer to chromosome positions. For example, in list `x`, `'2_12_20'` refers to chromosome 2 between positions 12 and 20.

Similarly, in list `y`, `'2_16'` refers to chromosome 2 at position 16.

What I would like to do is determine which chromosome position pairs in `y` fall within the range in each element in list `x`.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
x_new = list(map(lambda z: tuple(map(int,z.split('_'))),x))
y_new = list(map(lambda z: tuple(map(int,z.split('_'))),y))

def check_in_range(number):
    for i in y_new:
        if number[0] == i[0]: #if chromosomes match
             if number[1] <= i[1] and i[1] <= number[2]: #if position falls in range
                 return i
        else:
            continue #if chromosomes do not match, move on to next

answer = dict(zip(x_new, map(check_in_range, x_new)))
```

I would like my output to return a dictionary, where the elements in `x` are the keys and the values are any element in `y`.

My answer should be

```
{(2, 12, 20): [(2, 16),(2,18)], (2, 40, 60): None, (4, 45, 70): (4, 60)}
```

But I am getting

```
{(2, 12, 20): (2, 16), (2, 40, 60): None, (4, 45, 70): (4, 60)}
```

How do I alter my code so that it updates the dictionary if a key-value pair is already present?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out.

```
x_new = list(map(lambda z: tuple(map(int,z.split('_'))),x))
y_new = list(map(lambda z: tuple(map(int,z.split('_'))),y))

def check_in_range(number):
    list_a = []
    for i in y_new:
        if number[0] == i[0]: #if chromosomes match
             if number[1] <= i[1] and i[1] <= number[2]: #if position falls in range
             list_a.append(i)
        else:
            continue #if chromosomes do not match, move on to next
   return(list_a)

answer = dict(zip(x_new, map(check_in_range, x_new)))
```